# Why my AWS Lightsail instance got "Health Check: Failed" when attach to a load balancer?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail, amazon-elb

I created an `AWS Lightsail instance` and a `Load Balancer` also in `AWS Lightsail`.
When I attached my instance to the load balancer, I got this status: `Health Check: Failed`. I don't know why? I go to my WordPress and everything works fine.

Updated:
As I know, the LB only check my instance health on port 80, which is HTTP protocol. I have checked it and it always return `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`. I have already add these in **httpd-prefix.conf**:

```
SetEnvIf x-forwarded-proto https HTTPS=on

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

And these in **wp-config.php**:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

And these in **bitnami.conf**:

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(:[0-9]+)?$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

And restart my apache but it still not works.

Comment: How have you defined your health check?

Comment: Check the expected status code in your HCs. By default it is 200, but wordpress may be returning 302 or 303 for automatic redirection.

Comment: @petern In the document, they said `Lightsail performs health checks on your instances at the root of your web application ("/")`. And my site is working.
@Marcin how can I do the _Check the expected status code in your HCs._ sir?

Answer (score 1):

So I found a work around solution on topic: https://community.bitnami.com/t/lightsail-load-balancer-failed/81546/13

Following that, I need to create a file `health.txt` customize my health check path to this file: `http://{MY_IP_INSTANCE}/health.txt`.

And add these to my **bitnami.conf**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !health.txt
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Then restart my apache server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with AWS lightsail instances using lightsail CDN. This is how I fixed the health failure problem:

1. Click your lightsail instance
2. Connect using SSH
3. Navigate to **/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs**
4. Create an empty HTML file by running the following command:

   `touch health.html`
5. Reboot your instance